# Имя "Resource" не существует в текущем контексте. Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему? Пробовал пересобирать решение, перезапускать студию, ничего не помогает. Создаю пустой проект Xamarin.Android, ничего не добавляя и такая вот ошибка.

Comment: А если закомментировать эту строку, сделать Rebuild, и потом раскомментировать её назад?

Comment: Покажите, какие библиотеки используете в данной странице? У вас просто нет правильной "using" на ресурсы.